# How to develop a Ruby array

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a factorised array of n dimensions and I would like to develop it.

Here is an example:

```
develop([:a, :aa]) #=> [[:a, :aa]]
```

...which is the same as: `[:a].product([:aa])`.

Or, more complicated:

```
develop([:a, [:aa, :bb]]) #=> [[:a, :aa],
                               [:a, :bb]]
```

I'm working with Ruby 1.9.  Thank you for any idea.

*Edit:*

Another example, with 3 levels of embedded arrays:

```
develop([:a, [[:b, [:ba, :bb]],
              [:c, [:ca, :cb]],
              [:d, [:da, :db]]]]) #=> [[:a, :b, :ba],
                                       [:a, :b, :bb],
                                       [:a, :c, :ca],
                                       [:a, :c, :cb],
                                       [:a, :d, :da],
                                       [:a, :d, :db]]
```

I wonder if we could use Array's product method (http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-product), even if we have some embedded arrays.

Comment: Fun problem.  Homework?  :)  You can do the shallow case with a simple use of `map`.  Have fun with the deep case.  These algorithms are great to write in Ruby.

Comment: No no, it's not a homework ;) Hmm, I see. But perhaps deep case is overkill... I hope there's also a more light way to do this.

Comment: No answers after 8 minutes?  Okay well here is the shallow case for you: `def develop(a); a[1].map{|x| [a[0],x]}; end`  Let us know if you have trouble extending it to the deep case, unless of course it is a real homework problem.

Comment: Didn't see your last comment when I wrote my last one.  I can whip up the deep case for you.  Might take a couple minutes, though.

Comment: Actually, I suppose there's an other way than a deeped case map n time... Do you see if it's possible, @Ray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do to these poor arrays, but I managed to make a function that gives the correct output for both the cases you specified.  Here is the complete code:

```
def develop(x)
  return x unless x.is_a? Array
  y = []
  x[1].each do |s|
    d = develop(s)
    d = [d] unless d.is_a? Array
    d.each do |t|
      t = [t] unless t.is_a? Array
      y << [x.first] + t
    end
  end
  return y
end

x = [:a,
        [
            [:b, [:ba, :bb]],
            [:c, [:ca, :cb]],
            [:d, [:da, :db]]
        ]
    ]

p develop(x)

p develop [:a, [:aa, :bb]]
```

The output is:

```
C:\Users\David\Documents\scraps\test_ruby>ruby test.rb
[[:a, :b, :ba], [:a, :b, :bb], [:a, :c, :ca], [:a, :c, :cb], [:a, :d, :da], [:a, :d, :db]]
[[:a, :aa], [:a, :bb]]
```

***EDIT 1***:  Here's a shorter version that also gives the right output:

```
def develop(x)
  return [x] unless x.is_a? Array
  Array(x.last).collect do |s|
    develop(s).collect do |t|
      [x.first] + Array(t)
    end
  end.flatten 1
end
```

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake through my last example. Apologies. I rewrite my post with some other example, in order to clarify it.

Comment: Does my answer still work?  Could you please click the Check Mark to accept my answer or tell me why it is now wrong?

Comment: Omg, in fact it was me. Sorry, your version is perfect!

Comment: I took the liberty of making two small changes to the short version: one to make it work for the OP's first example, and another to shorten it slightly.